# How to set up a more maintainable way of doing things based on multiple UISwitch states?

Tags: ios, swift

So I'm currently creating a password generator and setting up every combination of if statements checking what switches are enabled and do something based on that is annoying to code and maintain.

```
@objc private func mainButtonAction() {
        mainLabel.text = ""
        if secondViewController.lowercaseLettersToggle.isOn == true && secondViewController.uppercaseLettersToggle.isOn == false && secondViewController.numbersToggle.isOn == false && secondViewController.specialCharactersToggle.isOn == false {
            let lowercaseOnlyArray = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]
            mainLabel.text?.append(lowercaseOnlyArray.randomElement()!)
        } else if secondViewController.lowercaseLettersToggle.isOn == false && secondViewController.uppercaseLettersToggle.isOn == true && secondViewController.numbersToggle.isOn == false && secondViewController.specialCharactersToggle.isOn == false {
            let uppercaseOnlyArray = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"]
            mainLabel.text?.append(uppercaseOnlyArray.randomElement()!)
        } else if secondViewController.lowercaseLettersToggle.isOn == false && secondViewController.uppercaseLettersToggle.isOn == false && secondViewController.numbersToggle.isOn == true && secondViewController.specialCharactersToggle.isOn == false {
            let numberOnlyArray = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
            mainLabel.text?.append(numberOnlyArray.randomElement()!)
        } else if secondViewController.lowercaseLettersToggle.isOn == false && secondViewController.uppercaseLettersToggle.isOn == false && secondViewController.numbersToggle.isOn == false && secondViewController.specialCharactersToggle.isOn == true {
            let specialCharactersOnlyArray = ["`", "~", "!", "@", "#", "$", "%", "^", "&", "*", "(", ")", "-", "_", "+", "=", "[", "{", "]", "}", "\\", "|", ";", ":", "'", "\"", ",", "<", ".", ">", "/", "?"]
            mainLabel.text?.append(specialCharactersOnlyArray.randomElement()!)
        } else if secondViewController.lowercaseLettersToggle.isOn == true && secondViewController.uppercaseLettersToggle.isOn == true && secondViewController.numbersToggle.isOn == false && secondViewController.specialCharactersToggle.isOn == false {
            let lowercaseAndUppercaseArray = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"]
            mainLabel.text?.append(lowercaseAndUppercaseArray.randomElement()!)
        }else if secondViewController.lowercaseLettersToggle.isOn == true && secondViewController.uppercaseLettersToggle.isOn == false && secondViewController.numbersToggle.isOn == true && secondViewController.specialCharactersToggle.isOn == false {
            let lowercaseAndNumberArray = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
            mainLabel.text?.append(lowercaseAndNumberArray.randomElement()!)
        } else if secondViewController.lowercaseLettersToggle.isOn == true && secondViewController.uppercaseLettersToggle.isOn == false && secondViewController.numbersToggle.isOn == false && secondViewController.specialCharactersToggle.isOn == true {
            let lowercaseAndSpecialCharactersArray = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "`", "~", "!", "@", "#", "$", "%", "^", "&", "*", "(", ")", "-", "_", "+", "=", "[", "{", "]", "}", "\\", "|", ";", ":", "'", "\"", ",", "<", ".", ">", "/", "?"]
            mainLabel.text?.append(lowercaseAndSpecialCharactersArray.randomElement()!)
        }


        UIPasteboard.general.string = mainLabel.text
        mainButton.alpha = CGFloat(1)
    }
```

So as you see here you can see how confusing it is to read every if statement and how annoying it is to set every if statement up (I haven't even set every if statement up here because I'm here to find a way where I wouldn't have to do this). Does anybody have a solution to this?

Comment: I would start by using an [`OptionSet`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optionset) and use [`CharacterSet`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/characterset) to create your candidate character list

Answer (score 0):

Start with an empty array. Now check each switch one at a time — not using `else`, just a sequence of four `if` statements. Each time one of those is `true`, append the characters corresponding to that choice. When you've passed thru all four `if` statements, you will have all the characters in the array appropriate to that configuration. Now pick a random element from the array.

Pseudocode:

```
var array = [Character]()
if lowercase { append lowercaseChars }
if uppercase { append uppercaseChars }
if numbers { append numberChars }
if special { append specialChars }
pick a char
```